# jQuery (3.4.1 / 3.3.1) load.() don't work, found no solution so far

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm messing with jQuery `.load()`

Here is my code sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>load demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load('test.txt');
       });
     });
   </script>

   <body>
     <div id="div1">Old text</div>
     <button>Get new text</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't load neither on **Safari (OSX)** nor on **Firefox (Rasperian)**. I knew this question was asked many times, but no answer did really helped.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Is it throwing any errors? What network request does it send and what response does it receive?

Comment: I expect 'test.txt' cannot be found. Check the network panel in the browser's console/developer tools. Is it returning a 404?

Comment: @misorude sorry about the spelling

Comment: As far as I remember .load() doesn't work well locally due to browser CORS policies.

Comment: Add image of your console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery load() function doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701914/jquery-load-function-doesnt-work)

Comment: sorry about the spelling. it is returning anything, the file test.txt exists in the same directory as the the .html. How do I show error codes?

Comment: @Chrisp Your protocol starts with `file:///`? Are you running your files without server?

Comment: Also, your `<script>` tag should be _within_ the `<head>` or the `<body>`. (You have it between them.)

Comment: solved: the CORS  policies where the problem, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct but maybe your file is not fetch from correct location

You should also handle error if any

also check this [jquery-load-method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-load-method)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load('/test.txt', function( response, status, xhr ) {
     if ( status == "error" ) {
        alert( "Sorry but there was an error: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
     }
    });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery-3.4.1 `keypress()` event is not triggered for links on firefox at second time.
Initially, when screen loads, the event is triggered. Coming back from any other screens to previous screen, it is not triggered.